# windows server 2008: How to identify who is logged on to the server

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

My windows server 2008 allows only one user to login at a given time. When another user tries to remote login into the same server, the previously active user's session gets disconnected. This is creating few problems for us.

Can anyone tell me a way to find whether a user has already logged into the server/ to find currently active user without actually having to login into the server so that the already active user's session will not be disturbed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use psexec from Sysinternals to remotely run the command "quser". This will list all logged in users, along with whether they're at the console or on RDP.

That said, I don't think it should automatically take other sessions and I'm pretty certain you can have up to 2 as standard.

Answer (score 2):

Other way (with gui) -> C:\windows\system32\tsadmin.msc and add the server to your group to see which Sessions are connected.

Answer (score 0):

`query session` which is the same as `qwinsta`

```
query session /server:SERVER2
```

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785434(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785434%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_examples)

Comment: Remember there is also the console session available but if this is a regular problem you should buy more TS licences.

Comment: There's no console session in Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008R2.